# Modeling 4-D Data in Python (with timestamp)

Tags: python, pandas, schema, data-modeling, python-xarray

I have data that is a projection for certain days from now `n` (or associated with a certain date in the future) and has an `(x,y)` pair as the projection. So all in all I have `(x,y,n) = (x,y,z)` or 3-D data.

Now, I have historical measurements, as well. The `y` dimension has "depth" but x is fixed. So I have `(x,y,z,t)` where `t` is a `datetime.datetime` object.

My actual data is currently:

```
data = [(x, [(y0, t0),(y1, t1),(y2, t2),...,(yn,tn), z]
```

My questions: **(1)** Is there a natural way in python to store this format of data? Or, **(2)** is it over-engineering the problem and there is a natural database solution to this type of data storage?

Answer (score 3):

Use a pd.MultiIndex to represent the various dimensions

```
data = [('x', [('y0', 't0'), ('y1', 't1'), ('y2', 't2'), ('yn', 'tn')], 'z')]
d = [[x, y, z, t] for x, ys_ts, z in data for y, t in ys_ts]
d

[['x', 'y0', 'z', 't0'],
 ['x', 'y1', 'z', 't1'],
 ['x', 'y2', 'z', 't2'],
 ['x', 'yn', 'z', 'tn']]
```

Then make into a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=list('xyzt')).set_index(list('xzt')).y.unstack()
df

t    t0  t1  t2  tn
x z                
x z  y0  y1  y2  yn
```